# Python: Is there a loop function to summaries this?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, concatenation

i am creating a new column in my dataframe called column 3. This column needs to start at 0, then column 3 should = column 2 + the previous result (above) of column 3.
The code needs to be like the following for x=1 to x=1000, but summarised:

```
df.at[0,'column3']=0
x=1
df.at[x,'column3']=df.at[x,'column2'] + df.at[x-1,'column3']
x=2
df.at[x,'column3']=df.at[x,'column2'] + df.at[x-1,'column3']
x=3
df.at[x,'column3']=df.at[x,'column2'] + df.at[x-1,'column3']
........
x=1000
df.at[x,'column3']=df.at[x,'column2'] + df.at[x-1,'column3']
```

When I type the above individually it works, but when I try this:

```
for x in range(1,1000):
df.at[x,'column3']=df.at[x,'column2'] + df.at[x-1,'column3']
```

It gives me the error 'can only concatenate str (not "numpy.int64") to str'. All values in the dataframe are numbers (0-10) and there are no NaN values.

Comment: error when x=1?

Comment: Did you try to check what the value of `x` is when the error occurs? Did you try checking the corresponding values in the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'column2' : list(range(1, 1001))})
df['column3'] = df['column2']
df.loc[0, 'column3'] = 0
df['column3'] = df['column3'].rolling(2, min_periods=1).sum()
df
```

looking for this ?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by saying 'it does not work' ? don't run at all ... the result is wrong ?